# which reference should be added to wcf project so that program recognize requestUrl.GetComponents()?

Tags: wcf

I have copied a sample code to a wcf project  and it contains  $requestUrl.GetComponents$ ...  the program don't recognize it ( there is red line under it) ... which reference should I add to solve the problem ...?

Comment: Where exactly does it contain `$requestUrl.GetComponents$`? The `$` signs are not valid C# or VB.NET syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetComponents` is a method of the `System.Uri` class. You only need to reference the System.dll (which is on the great majority of the projects by default) to use that.

Comment: I used this code :    'var portString =System.Uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Port, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped);'   but it has red line yet ... :( ... it seems that GetComponents is not a method of URI class!

Comment: It has been there since version 2.0 of the framework - see [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getcomponents.aspx). Which platform are you using?

Comment: .net 3.5 ... I have a wcf program ... and it didn't work for me unfortunately ...

Comment: Your code is incorrect; you're calling the method as a **static** method; you need to call it on the Uri **instance** itself. Something like `var requestUrl = someCodeWhichReturnsRequestUrl; var portString = requestUrl.GetComponents(UriComponents.Port, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped);`